# Save Views added by the User

Tags: android, view, save, onsaveinstancestate

I started programming a few months ago, so please excuse me if the answer to this question seems obvious to you.

Currently I am working on an application where the user is able to add a EditText by clicking a button, which works fine. The problem is the added Views are deleted once the User leaves the application or rotates the phone.

Does anybody have an idea how I can save the dynamically added Views which the User added by clicking the Button?

Comment: can you share your code where you add your EditText?

Comment: Check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no limit to the number of EdtitText that will added to the screen on click of button. There are two things that has to be done here.

1) So when you change the orientation the views are removed. To solve this you can add this to your manifest file

```
<activity name= ".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

**NOTE:** If you are using a different layout for landscape mode , by adding these parameters the layout for landscape mode will not be called.

2) In order for you to retain the views that were added by user when user leaves(kills the application from cache) the application you have to save the added EditText count either by using [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) or using ORM like **greenDAO**, **Sugar ORM** or any other which you find suitable.

Hope this helps. :-)